# Urinal Algorithm - A Simple Optimization

Tags: java, windows, netbeans

I am a Programming II student and a first time poster first time poster. What could quite possibly be a very simple problem has boggled my mind for too long.

*Problem #3.
It is a well-researched fact that men in a restroom generally prefer to maximize their distance from already occupied stalls, by occupying the middle of the longest sequence of unoccupied places. For example, consider the situation where ten stalls are empty.

---

The first visitor will occupy a middle position:

_ _ _ _ _ X _ _ _ _

The next visitor will be in the middle of the empty area at the left.

_ _ X _ _ X _ _ _ _

Write a program in Java that reads the number of stalls and then prints out diagrams in the format given above when the stalls become filled, one at a time. Hint: Use an array of boolean values to indicate whether a stall is occupied.

```
public class MenStall
{
public static int nextStall(boolean[] stalls) { . . . }
public static void printStalls(boolean[] stalls) {. . . }
. . .
}
```

Example of the output for the number of stalls = 10

_ _ _ _ X _ _ _ _ _

_ _ _ _ X _ _ X _ _

_ X _ _ X _ _ X _ _

_ X _ _ X _ _ X X _

_ X _ _ X X _ X X _

_ X X _ X X _ X X _

_ X X _ X X _ X X X

_ X X _ X X X X X X

_ X X X X X X X X X

X X X X X X X X X X

I assumed that the simplest way (with the little knowledge of programming that has been imparted to us this semester) to do this would be by declaring the end of the array and the start of the array as variables, and finding the middle by subtracting the start from the end and dividing by two. Unfortunately, beyond that I am stuck. I am not well versed in coding terminology, so for that I apologize. I suppose it would be simpler to show my attempt at tackling this issue:

```
public class MenStall

{

public static int position = 0;
public static int nextStall = 0;
public static boolean[] stalls = new boolean[10];
public static final int TRUE_END = stalls.length;
public static final int TRUE_START = 0;
public static int start = TRUE_START;
public static int end = TRUE_END;
public static final int TRUE_MID = (TRUE_END - TRUE_START) / 2;
public static int mid = TRUE_MID;

public static int nextStall(boolean[] stalls) 
{  
    if (position == 0)
    {
        nextStall = mid;
    }
    else
    {
        if (position % 2 == 1)
        {
            end = mid;
            mid = (end - start) / 2;
            nextStall = mid;
        }

        else if (position % 2 == 0)
        {
            mid = (end - start) / 2 + TRUE_MID;
            nextStall = mid;
            end = mid;
            mid = (TRUE_END - TRUE_START) / (int)Math.pow(2,position);

        }
    }

    position++;
    return nextStall;
}

public static void printStalls(boolean[] stalls) 
{
    String[] s1 = new String[stalls.length];

    while (position < stalls.length)
    {
        nextStall(stalls);
        stalls [nextStall] = true;
        for (int i = 0; i < stalls.length; i++)
        {
            if(stalls[i] == true)
            {
                s1[i] = "x";
            }
            else
            {
                s1[i] = "_";
            }
        }
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(s1));
    }     
}

public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    printStalls(stalls);
}

}
```

Toward the very end of the nextStall method, I was pretty much just playing with the numbers from how stuck I was. I certainly gave it my most earnest effort, and even had to ask the professor for an extension, but I cannot for the life of me figure this out. Any guidance would be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: I don't think I'd try to use a divide and conquer algorithm here - just a linear scan of all stalls, keeping track of the longest sequence of empty stalls, should be fine.

Comment: A little late to the game for this, but it seems that the algorithm should prioritize next to the walls before placing next to a person.

Answer (score 4):

Seems to me that using `BitSet` it's simpler than `boolean[]` array as `BitSet` has the predefined method `nextSetBit` which returns (as its name says) next set bit. I think, the divide-and-conquer strategy is unnecessary for your task. The problem can be solved like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int numStalls = 10; // get it from user input if you like
    BitSet bs = new BitSet();
    // set the leftmost and the rightmost bits (which represent walls)
    bs.set(0);
    bs.set(numStalls+1);
    // now we have 10 bits gap, which represent stalls
    // like this: X__________X
    for(int i=0; i<numStalls; i++) {
        bs.set(nextStall(bs));
        printStalls(bs);
    }
}

public static int nextStall(BitSet bs) {
    int bestPos = 0, maxDist = bs.nextSetBit(0);
    // iterate over the set bits
    for(int pos = maxDist; pos != -1; pos = bs.nextSetBit(pos+1)) {
        int dist = bs.nextSetBit(pos+1) - pos;
        // track the position of the stall with biggest gap on the right
        if(dist > maxDist) {
            maxDist = dist;
            bestPos = pos;
        }
    }
    // return the position on the middle of the best gap
    return bestPos+maxDist/2;
}

public static void printStalls(BitSet bs) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    // Iterate over all the bit positions except the walls
    // walls have positions 0 and bs.length()
    for(int i=1; i<bs.length()-1; i++) {
        sb.append(bs.get(i) ? "X" : "_");
    }
    System.out.println(sb);
}
```

If Java-8 is allowed, the solution can be even shorter:

```
public static int nextStall(BitSet bs) {
    // Find the position of the stall (or wall)
    // For which the next stall/wall is the most distant
    // bs.stream() returns stream of positions of the set bits
    int pos = bs.stream().boxed()
                .max(Comparator.comparingInt(v -> bs.nextSetBit(v+1) - v)).get();
    // Return the middle position in the gap
    return (pos+bs.nextSetBit(pos+1))/2;
}

public static void printStalls(BitSet bs) {
    // Iterate over all the bit positions except the walls
    // walls have positions 0 and bs.length()
    System.out.println(IntStream.range(1, bs.length() - 1)
            .mapToObj(idx -> bs.get(idx) ? "X" : "_").collect(Collectors.joining()));
}
```

Comment: Although this was extremely efficient in solving the problem at hand, I am, unfortunately, forced to use a boolean array for this problem, as I am only a couple of weeks into the class & have not gotten much farther than the topics of arrays and array lists. Is there any way this can be done using the divide and conquer method?

Comment: instead of maxDist = bs.nextSetBit(0) in nextStall method you can set maxDist = 0;  Because nestSetBit(0) will always output 0 as in the main method bs is set to 0.

Answer (score 2):

C++ solution for this problem using Priority Queue

```
#include<iostream>
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
struct s
{
    int distance;
    int start;
    int ending;
};
struct fn
{
    bool operator()(s const&a,s const &b)
    {
        if(a.distance!=b.distance)
        {
            return a.distance<b.distance;
        }
        return a.start<b.start;
    }
};
int main()
{
    int n;
    cin >> n;
    int mat[n] = {0};
    priority_queue<s,vector<s>,fn> q;
    struct s temp;
    int l=1,r=n,coun=1;
    q.push({n,l,r});
    while(!q.empty())
    {
        temp = q.top();
        q.pop();
        int left = temp.start;
        int right = temp.ending;
        int mid = (left+right)/2;
        if(temp.distance>0)
        {
            if(right>mid)
            {
                q.push({right-mid,mid+1,right}); // first push right child then left
            }
            if(left<mid)
            {
                q.push({mid-left,left,mid-1});
            }
        }
        mat[mid-1] = coun;
        coun++;
        for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
        {
            if(mat[i]==0)
            {
                cout << "_" << " ";
            }
            else
            {
                cout << "X" << " ";
            }

        }
        cout << endl;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems similar to level order traversal of a binary tree i.e at each level you divide the problem further into 2 sub problems. So use a queue to implement the same.

So what I mean by that is say initially you have l=0,r=n-1 where n is the size of input or number of urinals.

Then what you do is take mid = (l+r)/2 and place a person there,and then push (l,mid-1) and (mid+1,r) in the queue.

Repeat this process till the required urinals have been filled.

Comment: The this level of (missing) detail I don't think this is useful for the OP.

Answer (score 0):

This should work I guess.

```
import java.util.*;

public class hinata {
static Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
public static void main(String[] args){
    bfs(5,10);
}
static class node{int left, right,level; node(int left, int right, int level){this.left=left;this.right=right;this.level=level;}}
public static void bfs(int lev, int n){
    LinkedList<node> queue = new LinkedList<>(); boolean[] arr = new boolean[n];
    queue.addLast(new node(0,n-1,lev));
    int e = lev;
    while(!queue.isEmpty()){
        node curr = queue.removeLast();
        int l = curr.left, r = curr.right;
        if(e <= 0){break;}
        else{
            int mid = (l+r)>>1; arr[mid] = true;
            System.out.print(e+" : ");print(arr);
            --e;
            if(mid+1 <=r){
                queue.addFirst(new node(mid+1,r,e));
            }

            if(l <=mid-1){
                queue.addFirst(new node(l, mid-1,e));
            }
        }
    }
}

static void print(boolean[] arr){
    for(boolean i : arr){
        if(!i){System.out.print('_');}
        else{System.out.print('X');}
    }System.out.println();
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the C++ code for the same!

```
#include <iostream>
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int n;
    cin>>n;
    string s="";
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
        s+="_";
    }
    
    priority_queue<pair<int, int>> pq;
    pq.push({n,0});
    for( int i=0; i<n; i++){
        pair<int, int> front= pq.top();
        pq.pop();
        int indx= (front.first-1)/2+ front.second;
        s[indx]= 'X';
        cout<<s<<endl;
        pq.push({indx- front.second, front.second});
        pq.push({front.first/2, indx+1});
    }
    return 0;
    
}
```